# i want auto generated pdf attachment in send email using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, phpmailer

Anybody knows how attach automatically auto-generated pdf using codeigniter and phpmailer then,please help

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com');
$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

$this->email->send();
```

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't even try to create or attach a PDF. I suggest you start with the docs and examples provided with codeigniter and PHPMailer, particularly the `addStringAttachment` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly missing a couple lines of code...

i have also included pdf's in email after generating this is my code as example:

```
$pdf = $this->generatePdf();
foreach ($pdf as $p)
    $this->email->attach('./barcodes/' . $p . '.pdf');
```

---

now for some explenation:

```
$pdf = $this->generatePdf();
```

this is used to actually generate and store the pdf's, the result will be an array with the names of the actual pdf.

```
foreach ($pdf as $p)
        $this->email->attach('./barcodes/' . $p . '.pdf');
```

is used to loop through the array of generated pdf names and to actually include them, codeigniters email library has an `attach` function which allows you to add an attachment.

Comment: You never explained `generatePdf()`... that is not a native PHP or CodeIgniter function, so he can't simply add your lines of code without making new problems.

Comment: as i stated before i simply showed some code as an example, im not here to write code for someone else im here to help them understand why their code is not working as intended.

Comment: I agree... then please don't answer the question if you think the OP is lazy or don't feel like writing enough code to explain it properly.  The point of this site is to create a quality repository of Q&A that helps everyone in the future.

Comment: @Sparky IF i would had also given the entire code for the `generatePdf()` then i would had actually have written entire pieces of code for him instead of showing that he did not use the correct function for the attaching of the email.